# Need bash script line to log in to WordPress with curl/wget or similar on daily basis with cron

Tags: wordpress, bash, curl, post, wget

I have an endpoint URL that needs to be hit daily to execute an API call. It requires login. I can't seem to get a cURL or wget command that will successfully log in. I've tried this cURL command:

```
/usr/bin/curl -L --silent --data 
"log=login&pwd=password&ag_login_accept=1&ag_type=login" 
https://www.the-url.com 2>&1 | /usr/bin/mail -s "subject" 
email@domain.com
```

but the output is html of the login page, not the api output I get if I manually log in and then go to the url.

I also tried wget:

```
wget --save-cookies ~/sites/scripts/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies 
--post-data="log=login&pwd=password&ag_login_accept=1&ag_type=login" \ 
"https://www.the-url.com"
```

with the same result.

Comment: You'll need to do two requests, one to do the login and one to get what you're looking for. You'll need to keep cookies in a file as well, so the two requests can share them.

Comment: I tried a php script from https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/logging-into-wordpress-remotely-with-curl.929215/ and it may be working...I may answer my question with this if it turns out to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

WPUSR=user_name_goes_here
WPPWD=password_goes_here

COOKIEFILE=`mktemp`
COPT="--load-cookies $COOKIEFILE --save-cookies $COOKIEFILE --keep-session-cookies"
WGET="wget -nv -q ${COPT}"
MSG=`which banner || which figlet || which echo`

function printout() {
    links -dump ${1} | grep -v "^ *$" | grep -A 10 "Skip to content"
    }

function message() {
    $MSG "$1"
    }

# login
message 'Login'
    LOGIN="log=${WPUSR}${LOGIN}&pwd=${WPPWD}"
    LOGIN="${LOGIN}&redirect_to=http://127.0.0.1/wp/?p=1"
    ${WGET} -O page_01.html --post-data="${LOGIN}" 'http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-login.php'
    printout page_01.html

# show post
message 'View Post'
    ${WGET} -O page_02.html 'http://127.0.0.1/wp/?p=2'
    printout page_02.html

rm "${COOKIEFILE}"
```

output:

```
| |    ___   __ _(_)_ __  
| |   / _ \ / _` | | '_ \ 
| |__| (_) | (_| | | | | |
|_____\___/ \__, |_|_| |_|
            |___/         
   Skip to content
   Sitename
   Sitename
   Just another WordPress site
   Posted on 2018-04-11 by jmullee
                                  Hello world!
   Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then
   start writing!
One Reply to “Hello world!”
    1. A WordPress Commenter says:
       2018-04-11 at 16:05
__     ___                 ____           _   
\ \   / (_) _____      __ |  _ \ ___  ___| |_ 
 \ \ / /| |/ _ \ \ /\ / / | |_) / _ \/ __| __|
  \ V / | |  __/\ V  V /  |  __/ (_) \__ \ |_ 
   \_/  |_|\___| \_/\_/   |_|   \___/|___/\__|

   Skip to content
   Sitename
   Sitename
   Just another WordPress site
                                  Sample Page
   This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will
   stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most
   themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to
   potential site visitors. It might say something like this:
     Hi there! I’m a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night, and this
     is my website. I live in Los Angeles, have a great dog named Jack, and I
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion, connect to ssh from a **php bash script**:

Additional php package needed: **php-ssh2**

> sudo apt install php-ssh2

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$connect = ssh2_connect('20.32.66.66.xx', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connect, 'root', 'PtrDHfutyxxx');
$shell = ssh2_shell($connect, 'xterm');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connect, 'ls -a'); // Example command execute ls
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out); // Output command result
// ...
```

It is a base, fine to use **from the shell** over a **vpn**.

To avoid passwords in scripts, and secure it one level up, use crypto key pairs for logging.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-publickey-init.php